# Drop the [stackexchange] tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta, retag-request

Since the split, the [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) tag is no longer relevant, but people are still using it to tag new questions here. Back when this site was Meta Stack Overflow, this tag was used to indicate if a question specifically applied to the Stack Exchange network of sites, while the [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag was used to indicate Stack Overflow-specific questions. However, this site's scope is now the entire Stack Exchange network, making it redundant.

Can it be mass-removed?

Comment: Meta tags on meta... heh. Also there's an actual meta tag on meta!

Comment: There are a lot of old questions that should stay here as historical reference. Not all of them have been migrated to MSO.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: No one is suggesting removing questions, just the tag.